# Request is being sent to server twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am submitting a form to server using following method:

**`HTML Form`**

```
<form class="navbar-search pull-left" onsubmit="return mera()">
<input placeholder="Search" class="search-query span2" name="query" type="text" id="query" style="width:300px">
</form>
```

**`Method`**

```
<script>
function mera() {
   alert('this is something!');
   var query = document.getElementById('query').value;
   window.location = '../Translation/Search_Query?query=' + query;
   return false;
 }
</script>
```

It sends `request` twice to server on single submission. But shows `alert` only once for first time. How to fix it ?

Comment: Then there's more code than this. Changing `window.location` loads a new page, and the return value of `mera` is never used. Unless... `#query` doesn't exist.

Comment: How do you know it is sending it twice?

Comment: i have checkpoint at server side! it hits twice ! @putvande

Answer (score 2):

You dont need javascript. Simply use `GET method`

HTML :

```
<form class="navbar-search pull-left" method="GET" action="../Translation/Search_Query">
    <input placeholder="Search" class="search-query span2" name="query" type="text" id="query" style="width:300px">
</form>
```

When you submit the form, this will become :

```
http://example.com/Translation/Search_Query?query=query
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
function mera() {
   alert('this is something!');
   var query = document.getElementById('query').value;
   window.location = '../Translation/Search_Query?query=' + query;
    return true;
 }
</script>


<form class="navbar-search pull-left" onsubmit="return mera();">
```

Comment: it is not sending even a single request and page is refreshed!

Answer (score -1):

why dont you change you code a bit. only thing is it will post the value instead of get.

```
<form class="navbar-search pull-left" action="../Translation/Search_Query">
```

it will submit your value once you submit the form.

Note : you might need to change the action as per your servlet mapping.

**UPDATE**

```
<script>
function mera() {

document.getElementById('testForm').submit();
 }
</script>


<form id="testForm" class="navbar-search pull-left" onclick="mera();" method="GET" action="../Translation/Search_Query">
```

Comment: facing same problem !

Comment: And of course you can add `method="get"` to the `<form>` tag make it GET instead of POST...

Comment: @baqer_naqvi : what is ../Translation/Search_Query pointing to.

Comment: M working in MVC4 and its a controller method. @APaul

Comment: @baqer_naqvi Can you try my updated answer and check if it works for you.

Comment: twice ! still no hope! @APaul

Comment: @baqer_naqvi Just trying to help you buddy. Dont count it :) I am quite sure its not a issue connected to your html or javascript otherwise all the answers should fix it. Anyway, dont have any idea. Later if you find the fix yourself post it, it will help others.

Comment: yah @APaul i'm agree with u ! God help me! :)